# Unable to Roll Back transaction in asp net core boilerplate

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

I am trying to implement roll back the transaction in asp net boilerplate, so if the delete of the subsequent entity throws an exemption I need to roll back the delete of the previous entity, with the following code, the first delete is committed and is not rolled back on catch of exemption, and help over why is much appreciated.

the controller

```
public ActionResult Expense_Destroy([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, TS_Expense_ViewModel expenseVM)
    {
        if (expenseVM != null)
        {
            try
            {
                //Delete The Expense and Expense Audit.....
                _iTS_Emp_Expense_AppService.Delete(expenseVM.TS_Expense_VMID);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string exmptionText = _exemption_AppService.GetTimeTenantUserStamp + ex.Message;
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, exmptionText);
                Logger.Error(exmptionText + ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }

        return Json(new[] { expenseVM }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }
```

then the application services

```
 public void Delete(int id)
    {
       //Delete Expense.
       _iTS_Emp_Expense_Manager.Delete(id);

       //Delete Expense Audit.
       _iTS_Audit_Expense_Manager.DeleteByExpenseId(id);
    }
```

and the entity management survives

```
 public void DeleteByExpenseId(int id) //Expense Id
    {
        var expense = _repositoryAuditExpense.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ExpenseID == /*id*/88);
        if (expense == null)
        {
            throw new Exception(CustomMessageConsts.ServerGetError);
        }
        _repositoryAuditExpense.Delete(expense);
    }
```

what happens, if DeleteByExpenseId throws an exemptions, the _iTS_Emp_Expense_Manager.Delete(id); still commits the delete of the previous entity, I tried to manage the unit of work scope inside the application services by wrapping the two interfaces inside a using statement but this also did not work. the code I tried looks as follows:

```
public void Delete(int id)
    {
        using (var unitOfWork = _unitOfWorkManager.Begin())
        {
            //Delete Expense.
            _iTS_Emp_Expense_Manager.Delete(id);

            //Delete Expense Audit.
            _iTS_Audit_Expense_Manager.DeleteByExpenseId(id);

            unitOfWork.Complete();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using Abp repositories?

Abp by default uses unit of work for methods in domain and application layer so if you get an exception all was did before it's rolled back.

You can read asponetboilerplate documentation for more info.

Comment: Yes I am using Abp repositories, so _iTS_Emp_Expense_Manager inherits DomainService, and uses IRepository<Entity> and _iTS_Emp_Expense_AppService inherits ApplicationService, all repos are registered through Abp convention.